# FuelPHP to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller, integration, fuelphp

We were tasked to integrate fuelPHP to run in WordPress Website to gain the advantages these two offers to developers. We've been looking for methods over the internet on how to do it and we came to [this site](http://dragon-ark.com/archives/743).

We followed all the instructions, Yes, it successfully installed wordpress but failed to integrate with FuelPHP, when we tried to open fuelphp, it returned an error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Fuel\Core\Autoloader in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\game-bootcamp\fuel\core\classes\autoloader.php on line
>   24.

is there somebody there who successfully do it? Can you give us instructions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me for answering an old question, however it is not answered anywhere on the internet. This is important question because Wordpress is good for end-users, and Fuel PHP is very fast & good for programmers.

You can integrate Wordpress and Fuel PHP in two ways.

1. Wordpress to run in Fuel PHP
2. Fuel PHP to run in Wordpress

**The first way**

I bet you asked for the second one however you posted a link to tutorial for the first one. I can give you answer only for the second one.

Generally, the first way will be probably painfully, however here is some tip to get you started.
[Wordpress Codex - Integrating Wordpress with Your Website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

This way you can probably override using Wordpress themes and outputing anything and let the Fuel Request take the lead using Wordpress query functions. It seems as good way to integrate if you want Wordpress panel and Fuel PHP display, I don't think it's good idea at all, but if you want - go for it.

**The second way**

I wanted to achieve backoffice panel based on Fuel PHP and Wordpress website with the data taken from this backoffice panel with Fuel PHP classess inside Wordpress code.

This way you should leave the Wordpress application routing as it is and take advantage of HMVC pattern of Fuel PHP.

I have found this one which gave me the overall idea how to make this:
https://github.com/robertosobachi/wp-fuel-framework

**Step #1** - Wordpress basics

Do not modify Wordpress core. Do not modify Wordpress themes. Either create your own child theme or your own theme. If you want to make everything right - you should create Wordpress plugin for that.

You can then integrate Fuel PHP in functions.php file, however the best way is to create your own theme with Sidebar (Widget) Areas and create plugin which will make use of either theme-defined sidebars, defined PHP functions or/and shortcodes.

In your theme/plugin code you need to load Fuel PHP. You can make it on Widget Init action however it's your choice where to load this exactly.

The code below is for Fuel PHP 1.8, however you can probably go with further versions following this steps.

**Step #2** - Fuel index.php duplication

Let's assume following folder structure:

/apache/www/backoffice/ (with fuel and public folders)

/apache/www/wordpress/ (with wordpress)

Open the /apache/www/backoffice/public/index.php and see what's going there. The first thing to do is to duplicate the steps Fuel is doing but within Wordpress. Every code I paste should be placed in your Wordpress plugin or theme (as you like). ABSPATH is defined by Wordpress.

```
$dir = realpath(ABSPATH.'../backoffice/public');
define('DOCROOT', $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('APPPATH', realpath($dir.'/../fuel/app/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PKGPATH', realpath($dir.'/../fuel/packages/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('COREPATH', realpath($dir.'/../fuel/core/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Now you can copy the rest of Fuel index.php:

```
defined('FUEL_START_TIME') or define('FUEL_START_TIME', microtime(true));
defined('FUEL_START_MEM') or define('FUEL_START_MEM', memory_get_usage());

// Load in the Fuel autoloader
if ( ! file_exists(COREPATH.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoloader.php'))
{
    die('No composer autoloader found. Please run composer to install the FuelPHP framework dependencies first!');
}

// Activate the framework class autoloader
require COREPATH.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoloader.php';
class_alias('Fuel\\Core\\Autoloader', 'Autoloader');
```

The rest of the index.php code is based on the Request class which we don't want to use now, so do not copy it. However you can see the line:

```
require APPPATH.'bootstrap.php';
```

Let's go to that file. Inside in the first lines you can find:

```
require COREPATH.'bootstrap.php';
```

So let's start with this one first.

**Step #3** - CORE bootstrap.php duplication

It is save and probably required to copy the first lines of this file.

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('CRLF', chr(13).chr(10));

define('MBSTRING', function_exists('mb_get_info'));

require COREPATH.'base.php';

setup_autoloader();

get_composer();
```

**Do not copy** `register_shutdown_function`, `set_exception_handler`, `set_error_handler` unless you know what you are doing. You probably want to use default Wordpress error handling. Use fuel error handling is very tricky to do however if you want - try it. Personally I gave up.

**You have to copy** the `setup_autoloader` and `get_composer` functions. They are long, but they are crucial to make this integration works. I didn't copy it here to make this post more readable.

**Step #4** - APP bootstrap.php duplication

Hope you are not lost yet. We have to go back to APP bootstrap.php and copy this lines.

```
\Autoloader::add_classes(array(
    // Add classes you want to override here
    // Example: 'View' => APPPATH.'classes/view.php',
));

\Autoloader::register();

\Fuel::$env = \Arr::get($_SERVER, 'FUEL_ENV', \Arr::get($_ENV, 'FUEL_ENV', \Fuel::DEVELOPMENT));

\Fuel::init('config.php');
```

I am not sure if Fuel::init is so much important to load, haven't tested it yet. However you must be aware that Fuel::init method is setting some global variables like `date_default_timezone_set` (according to the config) so it can somehow modify the way Wordpress is working.

So, that's it. Now within your plugin/theme file you can make HMVC requests to your Controllers. You can access your models, Fuel classes - just like you used to do. Do not forget to activate your plugin in Wordpress.

```
$widget = Request::forge('widget/sample')->execute();
```

You have to be aware that it's not echoing the view automatically - see Fuel documentation for more.

Here is the pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/BchPmVbY)

**EDIT:**

There is another tricky part I found using sessions: when you are using only HMVC requests the Session is not saving so you have to call `Session::write()` manually within your code (wherever you want to save it). You will have to call it before the Wordpress output is made so try to hook to `init` or just place it in your main plugin file.

**EDIT #2:**

There is yet another tricky part with Wordpress auto "magic_quotes_gpc" feature. **Do not** simply turn this off by `$_POST = stripslashes_deep($_POST);` as it may break Wordpress security. The better way is to stripslashes right before adding to the database within your Fuel code and only those variables that you need to strip.